# Javascript Array Undefined without size

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to fill an array with a while loop. When I try to read the data at a certain index it keeps giving me undefined yet the length of the array tells me that there MUST be something added.

```
  var test = [];
  while (i < 16)
  {
    test[i] = i;
    i++;
    console.log(test.length);
    console.log(test[i]);
  }
```

Console output:

```
1
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 2
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 3
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 4
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 5
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 6
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 7
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 8
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 9
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 10
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 11
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 12
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 13
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 14
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 15
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
Fibbo.html:47 16
Fibbo.html:48 undefined
```

Comment: You insert `i` (0) into `test[i]` (`test[0]`), increase `i` (now, it is 1) and output `test[i]` (`test[1]`).

Comment: move `i++` to after `console.log(test[i]);`. you ar always trying to read the next array item

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are inserting at i and checking the value at i+1.This should fix your code -

```
  var i = 0;
  var test = [];
  while (i < 16)
  {
    test[i] = i;
    console.log(test.length);
    console.log(test[i]);
    i++;
  }
```

Comment: Don't you need to _initialize_ `i` as **0** ?

Comment: how is that more up votes are given since the code above is not working :) , i is undefined, undefined is not smaller than 16, i++ is NaN

Comment: @vtz The answer is fine. Just need to initialize i as 0.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal i agree but why are people just clicking automatically, this is bad.

Comment: Since the problem that @ScepT1c had was that he was seeing undefined, the assumption is that he has intialized i elsewhere.

Comment: Its because the key problem was solved and you may look for OP question there is console output where you can see 1 to 16 means OP is setting i value somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

yes change your code to

```
var test = [], i = 0;
  while (i < 16)
  {
    test[i] = i;
    i++;
    console.log(test.length);
    console.log(test[i-1]);
  }
```

i's value was incremented after you assigned value to it

Comment: When you will remove the console log (using uglify for example) the i will stop being incremented so it's a bad pratice. I did not downvoted but I guess this is why it was by someone else